# Are Variadic Templates Sufficient to Specify Constructive Types

Tags: c++, constructor, variadic-templates

My goal is to define a template to create a constructive type, e.g.:

```
MyCT := foo | bar of int | baz of WeirdClass | bat of (String, MyCT)
```

Internally, the prefix would be a byte value of an enumerated type, thus:
`{0}` or `{1,-20}` or `{2,{weirdo:WeirdClass}}` or `{3,{"Like I said",0}}` or `{3,Pair<String,MyCT>{"a",{1,626}}}` or the like.

It would look like the `...` syntax of variadic templates might help, but I am concerned about the following points:

1. Can a multiple number of constructors be created corresponding to the number of enumerated values?
2. If the number of enumerated values is not equal to the number of corresponding types, can we throw a compile-time error?
3. The type created by the template would itself be a template of the form `MyCT<ET>`, where `ET` is the enumerated type. How do we assure that we can use just the constructor corresponding to the enumerated value?
4. Can we throw a compile-time error if, in `MyCT<et>`, `et` is not in `ET`, the enumerated type for the template?
5. Can we do this so that `MyCT<foo>` would type match `MyCT<baz>`?

Comment: The question is not clear. I don't see where the *compile-time|runtime* barrier is on this: Why enum tagging? Are that enum values specified at runtime? If everything its provided at compile-time, I think we could redesign this easily and get it working using a bit of template metaprograming.

Comment: The goal is commendable but not really achievable. My sincere recommendation is to forget about it. If you want ML or Haskell, you know where to find them.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Manu343726. The following should not compile and should give a compile-time error:

ConstrType<ET,void,int,WeirdClass>

because ET has four values and only three types are supplied. This should be easily handled by checking the syntax.

Let's say we have a constructive type template with the proper syntax and instantiated it something like this:

template <ET et>
public class MyCT<et>;

template <ET et>
public class MyCT<et> : ConstrType<ET,void,int,WeirdClass,Pair<String,MyCT<et>>>{ ... }

(syntax aside) we would want strict typing on et in MyCT<et>.
No MyCT<blort>.

Answer (score 0):

To make this a bit more interesting, let us also define a (recursive) function `fuz` on this constructive type, in ML-like syntax:

```
let rec fuz = fun (foo)      -> 4
                | (bar b)    -> 2 * b
                | (baz w)    -> w.eird
                | (bat(s,m)) -> length(s) - fuz(m);;
```

where (say)

```
#type WeirdClass = {eird:int};;
```

So here we go in C++ ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8101e416bca48cb)):

```
struct WeirdClass { int eird; };

struct MyCT { virtual int fuz() const = 0; };

struct foo : MyCT
{
    virtual int fuz() const override { return 4; };
};

struct bar : MyCT
{
    int b;
    bar(int b) : b(b) { }
    virtual int fuz() const override { return 2 * b; };
};

struct baz : MyCT
{
    WeirdClass w;
    baz(const WeirdClass& w) : w(w) { }
    virtual int fuz() const override { return w.eird; };
};

struct bat : MyCT
{
    std::string s;
    const MyCT& m;
    bat(const std::string& s, const MyCT& m) : s(s), m(m) { }
    virtual int fuz() const override { return s.length() - m.fuz(); };
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    bar r{-20}, c{626};
    baz z{{8}};
    bat a{"Like I said",f};
    bat t{"no templates needed",c};

    cout << f.fuz() << " " <<  r.fuz() << " "
         << c.fuz() << " " <<  z.fuz() << " "
         << a.fuz() << " " <<  t.fuz() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
4 -40 1252 8 7 -1251
```

No weird variadic templates needed.

Comment: Yes, I wanted the fully instantiated template to have that kind of ML functionality and have done something similar to this for term algebras. However, in this question, I was taking this a step further and wondering whether it was now possible to succinctly represent the naive implementation of a term algebra with C++. Apparently, this is not the case as of yet.

Comment: @CarlKlapper As a run-time solution, polymorphic types can be a straightforward translation of constructive types as shown by my example. The mixed way you suggest in the question I believe is pretty much impossible. However pure compile-time may be an option, as C++ templates are extremely powerful. If you're interested, last year I implemented a miniature compile-time Scheme/CAML interpreter, unfortunately untyped, but even supporting imperative aspects like Scheme's `set!`. I stopped when the compiler once run for 10 minutes, taking up 24GB of memory, at least producing the right result :-)